# Linux get part of line's text if matched string in files

Tags: linux, string, file, grep, centos

In Linux, I have a file test.log that is similar to this:

```
2021/11/18 17:19:18,034 INFO {"queueName":"queue/RequestQueue",{"threadName":"WorkManager(2)-702","correlationID":"b67601e81bfd","requestData":"TYPE_1, REQUEST 1"}
2021/11/18 17:19:18,036 INFO {"queueName":"queue/ResponseQueue","correlationID":"TMYHxIyeYo","responseData":"TYPE_1, RESPONSE 1"} 
2021/11/18 17:19:18,038 INFO {"queueName":"queue/RequestQueue",{"threadName":"WorkManager(2)-885","correlationID":"j9BNzbbv3E","requestData":"TYPE_2, REQUEST 2"}
2021/11/18 17:19:19,172 INFO {"queueName":"queue/RequestQueue",{"threadName":"WorkManager(2)-183","correlationID":"d29d2d7cf5a4","requestData":"TYPE_1, REQUEST 3"}
2021/11/18 17:19:20,784 INFO {"queueName":"queue/esbRequestQueue",{"threadName":"WorkManager(2)-762","correlationID":"4235eba2765a","requestData":"TYPE_1, REQUEST 4"}
```

I want to search through all lines of this file and get the lines that have the string ["requestData":"TYPE_1] and write all of the requestData's content to another file called type_1.txt. Each matching line in the test.log file will be written to one line in the type_1.txt file. Below is my expected result in the type_1.txt file:

```
TYPE_1, REQUEST 1
TYPE_1, REQUEST 3
TYPE_1, REQUEST 4
```

My question is are there commands that can do this? I'm new to Linux so please help me with this.

Comment: This data looks incomplete, or at least it is not valid JSON?

Comment: It is not valid JSON...

Comment: You might use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) or perhaps [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) or write your C++ program using [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) or your C program using [jansson](https://digip.org/jansson/). I assume your real data is some *valid* [JSON](http://json.org/)

Comment: If it were valid JSON, jq would be great bet. However, jq cannot parse this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
grep -Po '(?<="requestData":")TYPE_1[^"]*' test.log > type_1.txt
```